# How to allow Unauthenticated users to reset password?

Tags: c#, asp.net

***Please see Update Below:***

I am using *ASP.NET SQL Membership Provider*.

So far I am able to allow users to change their password but only if they are ***authenticated*** or logged into the application.
What I really need is for users to be able to get a link in an email. They can click this link and reset their password.

Example: Lets say a user forgets his or her password, they can visit a page which they can either enter security question and answer; or their email address on file. They will then get an email with a link to reset their password.

All I have so far is this: Which allows only authenticated users to reset their passwords:

I do not want to use the Recovery Control which generates a password.

```
public void ChangePassword_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{

MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);

try
{
if (user.ChangePassword(OldPasswordTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text))
{
Msg.Text = "Password changed.";
}
else
{
Msg.Text = "Password change failed. Please re-enter your values and try again.";
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Msg.Text = "An exception occurred: " + Server.HtmlEncode(e.Message) + ". 
try again.";
  }
 }
```

I can create the store procedure and the email using a String Builder but I do not know how to get the ***un-authenticated*** user to change password. Is there a way for the user to be Authenticated when they click the link. I am not sure how to even ask this.

Thanks for reading:

**Update:**

Okay I managed to get the password to Reset using this code:

```
protected void btnResetPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string username = "ApplePie12";
  MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(username);
  currentUser.ChangePassword(currentUser.ResetPassword(), txtResetPassword.Text);
}
```

***Here is my plan:***

1. Make this page public so that it is access by *Un-Authenticated Users* but only via email link.
2. Create a Stored Procedure that verifies a user Exists either by the UserName they enter or by the Security Question/Answer.
3. If they exists, they are sent a link containing a token/GUID
4. Lastly when they click the link they will land on this page asking them to change password. **The Link Expires as soon as it is used.*

My only question is: Doing all of the above requires turning off using security Question/Answer in the Web Config file.

I really would love to have the Security question as an option for the user to either verify by email or security question. If this is not possible, I'll have to create some kind of account number or userid *(not membership user id)* as an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer is not specific to Membership Provider, but hopefully will point you in the right direction. Typically the way to approach this is to generate a very long random string, called a *token*. You send them a link that includes this token as a parameter, something like:

http://foo.bar/reset?token=asldkfj209jfpkjsaofiu029j3rjs-09djf09j1pjkfjsodifu091jkjslkhfao

Inside your application you keep track of tokens you have generated. If you receive a request containing that token, you authenticate it as if it was that user.

A couple notes:

- The token generated should be random and effectively unguessable in a short period of time.
- The token should only work for a short period of time after being generated, ideally shorter than the time required to guess it.
- The token should only be usable once. Once a user has changed their password using it, remove it from the system.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I did not think about this: So how do I authenticate a token? I am sure I can generate a GUID and HASH it. Once I know how to authenticate the token, I will be able to do this. Example: I can create a text box that allows user to enter email or security question. If it matches a GUID is generated, authenticated and email to the user??

Comment: This only works if you store unique emails. When a users asks for password reset, you ask for her email and send the token to the email and store the pair (email, token) somewhere. Then, when a token comes back, you just read the email and you have your user.

Comment: Yes I use unique email only, cannot be duplicate *Please see update above.

Answer (score 0):

Chris has given definitely the correct solution.

You can use the sql table for token management. the token may be UserId or Email that are unique. the link used for reset email like http://test.com/reset?id=sfksdfh-24204_23h7823.
    The id in the url is encrypted Userid or Email as you like.

Fetch the detail from table on the basis of id in Url. if id contain in database. then reset the password for user. and remove that token from DB.

Comment: Sehta, so if the token is in the DB, how do I authenticate it? As I explained above, I can create a textbox asking for email. if the email matches the user record, a token is taken from the db and emailed to the user. Now; a) What method do I use that will allow the password to be changes and how do I authenticate the token?

Comment: Decrypt the token. Fetch the token detail from Db acc. to UserId or Email i.e contain in URL. if this token match with the token from url. Give permission to change the password. fetch Memebership detail from the db with use of Email. and use the ChangePassword mathod.